# Avoid Sub Classing for every specific type

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I have a Interface called **Animal** which has 5 methods (abstract). Now in my Animal kingdom we have 1000(with 1000 different overridden method ) Animals(CAT,DOG,SNAKE....etc) but creating a 1000 different class for all the animals would be hectic and even when they created managing them would be really difficult , any suggestion would be appreciated.... visual presentation is available below.

```
                                         Animal(I)(5 Methods)
                                ---------------------------------------
                                |     |      |      |    ----------- |
                               DOG   CAT   SNAKE  LION              TIGER
```

My main goal is to reduce the number of classes .

NOTE: every animal is overriding one or more different methods and are truly different from each other

Comment: What do you mean by "truly different"? If they only differ in data (name, favorite food, etc.) you could consider storing these data externally (json, CSV, database, etc.) then loading the data to create the corresponding animals. If they also differ in behavior I think we'll need more details on what are the differences between them and how you plan to use them. Or, in other words, what are you trying to model, exactly?

Comment: Thanks For checking this . WHEN i say truly different that means it is different in functionality or behaviour like , Dog is barking and CAT is meau like that . and my problem is just because their behaviour is different , i dont want to keep adding the classes when a new animal comes to the kingdom

Comment: Well, both barking and mewing could be implemented as a simple `speak()` method which would print either "woof" or "mew" (which could be given as a constructor argument). We'll need more concrete differences between those animals (which methods are overridden and to do what). Moreover, who is supposed to use these classes, and for what purpose? To be honest, 1000 is _a lot_ and it looks unlikely to me that anyone would need/use all of them.